# How to find up similarly distributed control group for test group in sql?

Tags: sql, statistics, teradata

The task is pretty ambitious. I have about 50k+ users in each month, and I want to match up similarly distributed with same size control group from the full pool of users, which about 50 mln users. To get similar distribution I have some categorical and numerical features. The categorical features will be just `inner joined`. Numerical features would to like to round up, but that makes the biggest problem.

Here is my code:

```
with pl_subs as( -- in the cte I 
    select   al.*
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
      al.device_type
     ,al.report_mnth
     ,round(al.days_to_LAST_FLASH_DTTM, -1)
     ,round(al.LT_month, -1)
     ,round(al.REVC, -1)
     ,round(al.usg_in, -2)
     ,round(al.usg_AC, -1)
     ORDER BY null) AS RN
    from ai_pl_SUBS test_gr
    inner join  ai_SUBS_MONTH_CLR al 
    on al.cust_id = test_gr.cust_id
    and al.report_mnth = test_gr.REGISTERED_mnth
    where al.report_mnth  = '2017-11' and test_gr.REGISTERED_mnth = '2017-11'
)
sel count(1) -- just to count from (
sel al.cust_id, pl_subs.rn rn_pl
 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
  pl_subs.device_type
 ,pl_subs.report_mnth
 ,pl_subs.MCID
 ,round(pl_subs.days_to_LF, -1)
 ,round(pl_subs.LT_month, -1)
 ,round(pl_subs.REVC, -1)
 ,round(pl_subs.usg_in, -2)
 ,round(pl_subs.usg_AC, -1)
 ORDER BY null) AS RN
from pl_subs
inner join ai_SUBS_MONTH_CLR al on 

-- 2 categorilal features
pl_subs.device_type =  al.device_type
and pl_subs.report_mnth = al.report_mnth

-- 5 numerical features
and round(pl_subs.days_to_LF, -1) = Round(al.days_to_LF, -1)
and round(pl_subs.LT_month, -1) = Round(al.LT_month, -1)
and round(pl_subs.REVC, -1) = Round(al.REVC, -1)
and round(pl_subs.usg_in, -2) = Round(al.usg_in, -2) 
and round(pl_subs.usg_AC, -1) = Round(al.usg_AC, -1) 
-- in the control group shouldnot be any cust_id from the test group
where al.cust_id not in (select cust_id from ai_pl_SUBS)
    and al.report_mnth = '2017-11'
    ) _out where rn <=  rn_pl 
-- each 7 features determines strata. So I need to have so many cust as I have in appropriate  strata in the test group
```

People in the test group have higher numerical values. In the code above I  round up to tens, so intermediate spool wont be too big, but as I result only 36k users, not 50k as expected. I round up by 2 - the query will fail with spool problem

Similar distributed - have equal average for numerical values

Do I have any code mistakes? How the code can be modified to be possible the customer included to the strata multiple times?

Comment: You should ask *another* question with sample data and desired results.  I would also simplify the problem to just a handful of features and explain what "similar" means.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  NDA to give actual data and pretty tough to give even sample data. I will appreciate any possible approach here

Comment: Without additional details it's impossibe to help. This looks like a self join, it might be possible to replace it with some OLAP-functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code above has some problems:

1) `round(pl_subs.LT_month , -1) = Round(al.LT_month , -1)`  -- using rounds on widely distributed values will eventually cause problem on finding prober control client to test one. So just use cases:

```
case when LT_month <= 4 then '0'
     when LT_month <= 8 then '1'
     when LT_month <= 12 then '2'
     when LT_month <= 17 then '3'
     when LT_month <= 24 then '4'
     when LT_month <= 36 then '5'
     when LT_month <= 56 then '6'
     when LT_month <= 83 then '7'
     when LT_month <= 96 then '8'
```

Precomputing and using indexes will make the query to ran pretty fast. But don't overdo

2) CTE should contain only strata + the amount of people that group should to contain:

```
 with pl_subs as( -- in the cte I 
        select  
          al.device_type
         ,al.report_mnth
-- rounds should be changed
         ,round(al.LT_month, -1)
         ,round(al.REVC, -1)
         ,round(al.usg_in, -2)
         ,round(al.usg_AC, -1)
, count(1) as rn
from ai_pl_SUBS test_gr
    inner join  ai_SUBS_MONTH_CLR al 
    on al.cust_id = test_gr.cust_id
    and al.report_mnth = test_gr.REGISTERED_mnth
    where al.report_mnth  = '2017-11' and test_gr.REGISTERED_mnth = '2017-11'
group by 1
)

sel subs_id, report_mnth from (
sel al.subs_id, al.report_mnth, pl_subs.max_rn max_rn
 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
  pl_subs.device_type
 ,pl_subs.report_mnth
 ,pl_subs.segment
 ORDER BY null) AS RN
from pl_subs
inner join UAT_DM.ai_SUBS_MONTH_CLR al on 
pl_subs.device_type =  al.device_type
and pl_subs.report_mnth = al.report_mnth
and pl_subs.segment = al.segment
where al.subs_id not in (select subs_id from UAT_DM.ai_pl_SUBS)
    and al.report_mnth = '2017-11'

) _out where rn <=  max_rn;
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER ORDER BY NULL` can be replaced by a more efficient `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ... ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEING)` But this still looks like a complicated way to get a result similar to some OLAP-functions applied on the result of an outer join between ai_SUBS_MONTH_CLR and ai_pl_SUBS :-)